# Access 2010 Form.Repaint - Hanging

Tags: forms, ms-access, repaint

I'm hopefully missing something obvious here...

I have just kicked off developing a new Access 2010 application. Something personal and hopefully simple.

The first thing I need to do is read a bunch of files off of the hard drive. I parse the contents adding the information to a table if it doesn't already exist.

Code works fine, that's not the issue. As it can take a while I've added a simple progress dialog using a standard form but in dialog/popup mode. As the For Each loop of the FSO.Folder.Files object is progressed I send some information to a couple of text boxes and issue a Me.Repaint (have also tried DoCmd.RepaintObject acForm, "FormName").

The issue is that I can get anywhere from 5% to 35% of the process complete before the repaints stop responding. The form only repaints when it gets to 100%.

The process uses limited recursion - if there is a subfolder - it calls itself to process that subfolder, but the folder structure is fairly linear so not many of those.

There are nothing bound to the form. All table updates happen in code and via RecordSets.

Any ideas why Access stops responding?

Cheers,

Roy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `DoEvents` after `Repaint`.  That will cause Access to yield to Windows, which will can then handle its pending tasks ... such as updating the display in this case.

Actually, if your code updates text boxes, I don't see why you need to `Repaint` the form in order to display the changes.  Try something like this instead ...

```vb
Me.MyTextBox = "hello"
DoEvents
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked a treat! Thanks